# Бесконечная загрузка Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, android-emulator

[image: Весит уже минут 30 минимум]

На домашнем пк загружается за минуту 1-3 на рабочем в ожидании чуда , хотя конфиг пк домашнего и рабочего одинаковый

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего на рабочем компе не стоит [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/how-to-use-the-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm-android-emulator.html) - он не может там стоять по определению :)

Comment: Вот только вчера установил HAXM  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqeAy.png